# How stop framework from changing color of elements on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, frameworks, materialize

I making website using materializecss. I'm trying to make a Side Nav similar to one that is used on their [website](http://materializecss.com/).

I want to paint red the selected tab in my Side Nav, but it keeps becoming gray when i hover over it because of materializecss itself.

What is the good way to sometimes stop frameworks from doing things i don't want them to do?

Thank you.

EDIT - my code https://jsfiddle.net/9mek1r48/

```
     <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
            <li class="activeTab"><a href="#!" class="white-text">+Add Banner</a>            
            </li>
            <li><a href="#!">Test</a>            
            </li>
     </ul>
```

And style i created

```
.activeTab {
    background-color: #ee6e73;
    !important;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue - you may need to make your selectors more specific to the element you're targeting. Without seeing any of your code, that's about as much help as anyone can be.

Comment: I'm not familiar with materializecss, but with Bootstrap you'd have to overwrite the variables before you load the css. In your case, you probably have to do the same or overwrite the class with your own styles.

Comment: I added code for clarity. You may need to make area with page a bit bigger to see the nav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is at the top of my css file, that goes after the frameworks css file, add css rules that override the ones from the framework without editing the framework itself.

you want to add this to your css:

```
ul.side-nav.fixed li:hover, ul.side-nav.fixed li.active {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

changing the color to your taste.

edit: to stop changing try this:

```
ul.side-nav.fixed li:hover, ul.side-nav.fixed li.active {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: The problem is i don't want to "li" to change colors when i hover over it.

Comment: It just changes to color of the Nav, not to the color of the li. But i found a way to make it work. I closed li in to a div with background-color same as a li.